How to delete and set another cloud task?
I want to create a cloud task that will run in 1 day to hit an endpoint (java/spring boot). This endpoint will execute some code and then delete this task and create another one that will hit the same endpoint.
Is this possible?
Or can I just leave this executed task without delete it?
Or can I update the same task to run again next day?

The documentation is unclear but you can use Cloud Scheduler to invoke generic HTTP targets (not only Cloud Functions). See gcloud scheduler jobs create http. You can schedule this to run every day at a specific time (e.g. 00:00)

I can also agree with what @DazWilkin mentioned in the comment section. Cloud Scheduler is more for recurring tasks rather than one time reminders while Cloud Tasks product allows you to schedule a queue (consist of tasks) up to 31 days in the future. With Cloud Tasks you can target an AppEngine, or any arbitrary HTTP endpoint.
In Cloud Tasks, a task cannot be deleted if it has executed successfully (will be removed from the queue) or if it has been tagged as permanently failed, and can only be deleted if it is scheduled or dispatched. Also, tasks cannot be updated after creation because there is no UpdateTask command to begin with. You can refer to this documentation for more information.
You can also check this out to see the comparison of Cloud Tasks and Cloud Scheduler.
